Logging in with Auth0 in Cypress test
I am trying to sign into my local app using Auth0. I am copying the approach in the Cypress docs, but when I run the below test, I am getting this error:
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: The command was expected to run against origin https://dev-n2jrwg8j36hmpd5j.us.auth0.com but the application is at origin http://localhost:3000.

This commonly happens when you have either not navigated to the expected origin or have navigated away unexpectedly.

Using cy.origin() to wrap the commands run on http://localhost:3000 will likely fix this issue.

cy.origin('http://localhost:3000', () => {
  <commands targeting http://localhost:3000 go here>
})

This error occurred while creating the session. Because the session setup failed, we failed the test.

Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: Auth0

Here is my spec file:
describe('Auth0', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.intercept('POST', '/graphql').as('createBankAccount')
    cy.loginToAuth0(
      Cypress.env('auth0_username'),
      Cypress.env('auth0_password')
    )
    cy.visit('/')
  })

  it('shows onboarding', function () {
    cy.contains('Get Started').should('be.visible')
  })
})

cypress.config.js:
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
// Populate process.env with values from .env file
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = defineConfig({
  env: {
    auth0_username: process.env.AUTH0_USERNAME,
    auth0_password: process.env.AUTH0_PASSWORD,
    auth0_domain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    auth0_audience: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
    auth0_scope: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_SCOPE,
    auth0_client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENTID,
    auth0_client_secret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },

  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});

commands.js:
Cypress.Commands.add("loginToAuth0", (username, password) => {
    const log = Cypress.log({
        displayName: "AUTH0 LOGIN",
        message: [` Authenticating | ${username}`],
        // @ts-ignore
        autoEnd: false,
    });
    log.snapshot("before");

    const args = { username, password };
    cy.session(
        `auth0-${username}`,
        () => {
            // App landing page redirects to Auth0.
            cy.visit("/");

            // Login on Auth0.
            cy.origin(Cypress.env("auth0_domain"), { args }, ({ username, password }) => {
                cy.get("input#username").type(username);
                cy.get("input#password").type(password);
                cy.contains("button[value=default]", "Continue").click();
            });

            // Ensure Auth0 has redirected us back to the RWA.
            cy.url().should("equal", "http://localhost:3000/");
        },
        {
            validate: () => {
                // Validate presence of access token in localStorage.
                cy.window().its("localStorage").invoke("getItem", "authState").should("exist");
            },
        }
    );

    log.snapshot("after");
    log.end();
})

